# Infinite sum: $\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac{\ln x}{e^x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, summation

I have tried to find this infinite sum all over the place but could not find it.  Does anyone know a method for finding this sum:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}
\sum_{x=1}^n {\ln(x)\over e^x}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there any reason for suspecting a closed form exists?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form, or do you want to evaluate the sum numerically?

Comment: What do you mean with "over" in your code? Do you mean $\binom{\ln(x)}{e^x}$ or $\ln(x)^{e^x}$

Comment: @Cornman He means "divided by."

Comment: That is a good point egreg.  I suppose I would be just as satisfied if I could be some how shown that there cannot be any closed form solution.  If there is a closed form solution I would be looking for a method to find the closed form solution exactly. Not a numerical approximation

Comment: what have you worked out so far ?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives a closed form solution in terms of polylogarithms: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(ln+x+e%5E-x)+from+x%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: Wolfram comes out with [$$-\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac1e\right)$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+ln(x)%2Fe%5Ex+from+x%3D1+to+infinity)

Comment: If you look at the definition of [Polylogarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), you can see that your sum is equivalent to $-\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\mathrm{Li}_p\left ( \tfrac{1}{e} \right ) \right |_{p=0}$

Comment: Equivalent to integral: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\ln (n)}{\exp (n)}=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{(-1+e) t}-\frac{1}{\left(-1+e^{1+t}\right) t}\right) \, dt$

Answer (score 4):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{e^k}$$
It is easy to prove the convergence. That is not the question.

The question is about the existence, or not, of a closed form. In other words, if $S$ is related to a standard special function.

Consider the kind of special functions called "Polylogarithm" :
$$\text{Li}_\nu(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k^\nu}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-\nu\,\ln(k)}z^k$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}\text{Li}_\nu(z)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \ln(k)e^{-\nu\,\ln(k)}z^k=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{k^\nu}z^k$$
In the particular case 
$\quad\nu=0\quad\text{and}\quad z=\frac{1}{e}\quad$ this leads to 
$\quad \frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}\text{Li}_\nu(z)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{e^{k}}$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{e^k}=-\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial \nu}\text{Li}_\nu(z)\right)\left(\nu=0\:,\:z=1/e\right)$$
This special function is implemented in WolframAlpha as $\text{PolyLog}^{(1\,,\,0)}(\nu,z)$. The first exponent means the partial derivative with regard to $\nu$. The second exponent means the partial derivative with regard to $z$, which in the present case is of degree $0$, that is the function itself.

That is why WolframAlpha gives the result on the form :
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{e^k}=-\text{PolyLog}^{(1\,,\,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{e}\right)\simeq 0.1920928...$$